# Var-arg syntax in Java

Tags: java

```
private void setUuid(int.. uuid)  
{
  // method stuff
}
```

The Java 6 compiler complains when I try to use the syntax above .. Isn't the var-arg above valid ?

Comment: when the compiler complains about syntax, you check whether your syntax is correct. And guess whether you can find it in the first google result ;)

Comment: and by the way - a uuid can't be an `int`.

Comment: And BTW, I am not a native English speaker, but I tend to believe in written English you would use three periods too, not two of them.

Comment: in other words - it's not that we aren't willing to help, but it would just be a lot quicker and beneficial for you to do it yourself ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need three dots to make an argument a vararg.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the 1.5 language docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) it's three periods:

```
private void setUuid(int... uuid)  
{
  // method stuff
}
```